# Facebook Auth Dialog - Adjusting the text displayed

Tags: php, facebook, api, authentication

Just wondering if someone could point me in the right direction of how to change some text on the Facebook Auth Dialog. I've attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3mcm.png) of the information I wish to change, which I know is possible as I've seen it done on applications such as the Pinterest app.

Can't seem to see that section highlighted anywhere on! https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Auth Dialog uses an iFrame/separate window and therefore cannot be manipulated (design wise).

If you are simply changing permissions and text etc then use the app settings and the Auth settings here:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

If you actually want to redesign the screen then your only option would be embedding the Facebook iFrame on top of your content and making it transparent (not good practice). The Auth dialog must be hosted on Facebook's server for many reasons, therefore I am certain this cannot be done without ugly workarounds.

**UPDATE**
It seems that you would like to change the permissions that your application requests. This is is very easy using the HTML for your login button. Just add this to your element:

```
scope="user_about_me,publish_actions...(any other permissions you want)"
```

However, I fear that you may want to take this a little further and actually display things like this:

> This app shares routes you ran, loops you ran and other activity on
>   Facebook

Although this is pretty simple to implement using the Open Graph to add 'actions', you cannot simply write out the text. It generates it for you based on what actions you have.

**Is this what you are looking for? If so, I will explain in more detail how you can achieve it**

Comment: You can manipulate the text I think, because I've changed the Headline and the Description - The link I posted mentions information on those bits, just not on the bit that I mentioned in my post. Though it must be possible because it's been changed on the screenshots in the link and also on apps such as Pinterest. Hmm.

Comment: As I said, you can change text and headings pretty easily. Can you be more specific about what you want to change, there are a lot of images on the link you posted!

Comment: Sorry it looks the screenshot didn't attach, I've edited my original post now to add it.

Comment: @christian.thomas These are the permissions that your applications requests. These can be modified in both the app settings and the auth dialog javascript. I will edit my answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ben - It is indeed what I'm looking for. I want to display custom text in the box in the screenshot. So the application is about sharing items with friends, I'd want it to say something similar. I've tried adding the Open Graph tags, but now whenever I click 'Preview Dialogue' it starts to open, displays 'Loading' and then immediately closes. Some sort of Facebook bug I'd think. But presumably in the Open Graph tab I just add an action of 'borrow' and then list some of the objects? Thanks.

Comment: @christian.thomas, you are right!! There is a bug in the Open Graph preview dialog at the moment. Do not worry, it is not just you. I have got it aswell. Best thing to do is, create your actions and objects, and then just test your dialog on your site. Do you want me to amend my answer with instructions on how to add actions?

Comment: No that's fine, I think I've got it, I'll just wait till Facebook sort the dialog out! Appreciate your help Ben, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the copy on the Dialog from the the app settings on Facebook.  Settings-> Auth Dialog.